# How to get JSON from PHP json_encode function?

Tags: php, json, api

I am trying to make an API, but I have a problem: I want to output my data to the user using JSON.

PHP code:

```php
$JSONfeedback = [
        [
          "newURL"   => "$newURL",
          "orgURL" => "$orgURL",
          "create_time" => "$create_time",
          "clicks" => "$clicks"
        ]
      ];

  // Output the JSON
  echo json_encode($JSONfeedback);
```

Console output:

```
{"newURL":"https:\/\/shty.ml\/?y1MWzYW708","orgURL":"https:\/\/keep.google.com","create_time":"UNDEFINED","clicks":"2"}
```

But I want something like this:

```js
Object {newURL: "https://shty.ml/?y1MWzYW708", orgURL: "https://keep.google.com", create_time: "UNDEFINED", clicks: "2"}
```

So that the user could access all the info. How can I do that?

Comment: Please show your jquery code.

Comment: use  json_encode($JSONfeedback,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

Comment: My JSON code is in the image.

Comment: Is not working event i use the echo json_encode($JSONfeedback,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

Comment: you need parsing the JSON string to Object.. and you'll get what you want..see jQuery JSON [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

Comment: that is already a valid json ? array and object is valid json

Comment: please provide the plain text output instead of the pngs. the image hosting at imgur seems down currently, so no one can see what you want. json shouldnt need an image in the first place.

Comment: JSON is a ***string*** by definition. What you want is to turn that string into a native Javascript object.

Answer (score 3):

You are already getting JSON! I think what you are trying to do is have some frontend JavaScript interpret it as an object. That part is easy:

```
> var dump = '{"url":"http:\/\/www.google.com"}'; // the actual encoded JSON
> JSON.parse(dump) // convert it to a native object

Object {url: "http://www.google.com"}
```

Although it's very similar to plain JS objects, JSON is a method of encoding data structures for transmission over a network -- it is quite literally a string. It needs to be decoded before it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

That is the **`console.log()`** of your `echo json_encode()`. So when your javascript in any form get the json from your api, you can console.log() your object. So json_encode() is exactly what you need on php side.

Answer (score 0):

Check my code:

```
function example($arrays = array()) {
    $x = 1;
    $api_value = '{';

    foreach ($arrays as $array => $value) {
        $api_value .= $array . ': ' . '"' . $value . '"';

        if ($x < count($arrays)) {
            $api_value .= ', ';
        }
        $x++;

    }

    $api_value .= '}';
}

example([
    'newURL' => 'link',
    'orgURL' => 'link',
    'create_time' => 'UNDEFINED',
    'clicks' => '2'
]);
```

output:

```
{newURL: "link", orgURL: "link", create_time: "UNDEFINED", clicks: "2"}
```